# Scrollbars for code prettified using google-code-prettify

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, pretty-print

I am using [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for syntax highlighting in my blog which is hosted on blogger. My problem is I do not see the scrollbars appear around my pre-formatted code blocks even when the code is too wide to fit within the designated width. I am formatting the code blocks with

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-java prettyprinted" style=""> <code>public class MyVeryVeryLongClassname extends MyBaseClassWithAnEvenLongerName implements AnInterface, AnotherInterface, YetAnotherInterface { </code></pre>
```

On my blog, the scrollbars never appear and the line goes beyond the right edge of the post column (For example, take a look at [this post](http://curioustechizen.blogspot.com/2012/12/code-smells-calling-life-cycle-methods.html)), making it look very ugly. The same is displayed by StackOverflow as:

```
public class MyVeryVeryLongClassname extends MyBaseClassWithAnEvenLongerName implements AnInterface, AnotherInterface, YetAnotherInterface {
```

I used Firebug to look into how stackoverflow does this, and I couldn't spot anything different from what I am doing. I am linking to the same JS file as the one used by SO (on their own CDN). I'm also using the same styles.

So, what do I need to do to add the scrollbars to the pre-formatted code blocks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution. All I needed to do was to add the following CSS properties to the site-wide CSS style-sheet:

```
pre.prettyprint{
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 600px
}
```

This introduces the scrollbars.

Answer (score 10):

with your code everything goes to left side in my [blog](https://unity3diy.blogspot.com/),
but i fixed it using the following CSS code:

```
pre.prettyprint {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    width: auto;
    /* max-height: 600px; */
    white-space: pre;
    word-wrap: normal;
    padding: 10px;   
}
```

I found the code on [github](https://github.com/taywils/taywils.me/blob/master/static/css/style.less).

Comment: Actually i really dont know the difference, I found this css on github.[link](https://github.com/taywils/taywils.me/blob/master/static/css/style.less)